# Probability of a sequence balls draws with repetition

Tags: probability

I have got the following problem
[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbBsn.png)

and I want check whether my reasoning is correct or not for the first point $a)$
My solution is :
$P(RBRBRB) = (\frac{1}{2})^6 * 0.95 + (\frac{1}{2}) * 0.05$
However I am not sure whether instead it should be $P(RBRBRB) = {6 \choose 3}(\frac{1}{2})^6 * 0.95 + (\frac{1}{2}) * 0.05$

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your initial answer is correct, the added ${6 \choose 3}$ factor would change the meaning of the first part to the probability that the person extracts three $R'$s and three $B'$s in the first six extractions.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: you're most welcome